# Enable the checkbox on "Terms and conditions" scrolldown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My checkbox is checked to begin with, even though supposedly set to `false`. Checkbox get's checked whenever I scroll, doesn't go through the if statement.

https://jsfiddle.net/7mujuvn3/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //checkbox
    $('#box').attr('checked', 'false');
        $("#terms").scroll(function () {
            //the room for scrolling is 30px in the textarea
            if ($("#terms").scrollTop() === 30) {
                $('#box').attr('checked', 'true');
            } else {
                $('#box').attr('checked', 'false');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're missing `()` after `scrollTop`. `scrollTop` is a method.

Comment: doesn't work with the paranthesis either. I'll edit my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the quotes around `true` and `false`, use `prop` in all cases, and use parentheses after `scrollTop` to run it as a method. Also, you might want to use `>` for checking against `scrollTop`, since if it's both, greater or lesser than `30`, it will uncheck the box again.

https://jsfiddle.net/7mujuvn3/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //checkbox
    $('#box').prop('checked', false);

    $("#terms").scroll(function () {
        //the room for scrolling is 30px in the textarea
        if ($("#terms").scrollTop() > 30) {
            $('#box').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#box').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#terms {
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="terms" cols="30" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aliquid
    at dignissimos doloribus explicabo suscipit vero! Aliquam beatae, cumque dignissimos eum expedita, in maxime neque optio quae quidem quos ut?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto aut blanditiis deserunt doloribus ea, eaque impedit laborum minima non officiis placeat quasi quidem repudiandae. At dolores explicabo inventore necessitatibus</textarea>
<input id="box" type="checkbox" checked="">
```